# Autofill web forms

Tags: html, forms

Let's say that a website contains a search tool with advanced options.  I often use the same search criteria to perform my search.  It would be incredibly useful if I could use a script that enters predetermined settings to perform the setup (instead of me manually clicking checkboxes, dropdown lists and whatnot).

To illustrate with an example, here's a code snippet of the html page that I'm inspecting:

```
<li><input value="No" name="search[amMember]" type="radio">  
    Non-joined games
    <ul><li><strong>Joinable:</strong>
        <input value="-" name="search[isJoinable]" checked="" type="radio"> 
        All 
        <input value="Yes" name="search[isJoinable]" type="radio"> 
        Joinable 
        <input value="No" name="search[isJoinable]" type="radio"> 
        Not joinable 
    </li></ul>
</li>
```

This corresponds with a checkbox for **Non-joined games** and 3 sub checkboxes for **All**, **Joinable** and **Not joinable**.  **All** is selected by default, as denoted by `checked=""`.  The html code that would correspond with a predetermined check on, for example, **Not joinable**, would look like this:

```
<li><input value="No" name="search[amMember]" checked="" type="radio">  
    Non-joined games
    <ul><li><strong>Joinable:</strong>
        <input value="-" name="search[isJoinable]" type="radio"> 
        All 
        <input value="Yes" name="search[isJoinable]" type="radio"> 
        Joinable 
        <input value="No" name="search[isJoinable]" checked="" type="radio"> 
        Not joinable 
    </li></ul>
</li>
```

I have added the check on **Not joinable** and **Non-joined games** and removed it on **All**.  This corresponds with the checkboxes being marked for the first two values and unmarked for **All**.

I feel that something like this should exist, but I'm somehow unable to find it. There are autofill plugins available for both Google Chrome and Firefox, but they seem to fill in standard (predetermined) fields such as username, name, company name, address, etc.  If no plugins are available, is there a way I can create something custom to preselect and pre-enter my form values?  The idea is that I can click a script or link and get presented with a form that's already filled in, rather than me going through the same steps every time to select the same parameters.

PS: I'm not using the *autoform* tag on purpose because that seems to refer to autocompletion, rather than the autofilling that I'm talking about.

Comment: Are you somewhat experienced with JavaScript? You could write a userscript that changes the form through JS commands, then use Greasemonkey or Tampermonkey to load that script whenever you run the website. You could also add your own button or form to the website, which would allow you to select how the form should be pre-filled.

Comment: @slhck I know a little JavaScript.  I'm just a bit disappointed that a plugin does not currently exist yet.  I just figured a tool like this would exist already.  Perhaps I am underestimating the complexity involved of creating such a plugin.

Comment: @Babyburger, which website for example?